# DLE избавиться от URL http://сайт.ru/2017/10/11/

Tags: dle

Существует CMS DLE
Я удалила модуль - дата месяц год, убрала все упоминания и вывод в шаблон.

Но все равно каждый день при добавлении статей, появляются ссылки вида:

> сайт.ru/2017/10/11/

Как это можно исправить?

****С каждым днем страниц все больше, а они отдают 404 ошибку. Получается, через год у меня будет 365 404 ошибок,а через 2 свыше 700.

Comment: Какой результат вы хотите достичь? Ошибка 404 - это значит страница не найдена, если набрать сайт.ru/abrakadabra - тоже будет 404 ошибка в браузере. Если удалили модуль, а ссылки продолжают появляться, может что-то "недоудалили"?

Comment: а настройки ЧПУ там нету ?

Answer (score 1):

{date} - поищите по всему архиву с сайтом. 
Удалите все совпадения именно в папке шаблона.